# Dot syntax variable onto array

Tags: jquery, syntax, variables

I have an array of buttons that when clicked on, opens or closes content on my site. I need to be able to track which one is open so that when I click on that button again, I will know whether or not to close the content.

Here's my array:

```
var imageOptions = ['.corporateNeeds', '.marketResearch', '.corpStrategic', '.employeeTraining', '.administration', '.wellnessManagement'];
```

And the content that will open once you click on one of the buttons.

```
var options = ['.option1', '.option2', '.option3', '.option4', '.option5', '.option6'];
```

Then I loop through the array and show the content of whichever one was clicked on:

```
jQuery.each(imageOptions, function (k) {
    $(imageOptions[k]).click(function () {
        hideOptions()
        $(options[k]).fadeIn();
        $(options[k].contentOpen) = true;
    });

});
```

What I want to know is if there is a way of tracking the current clicked button by dot syntaxing a variable i.e. (**$(options[k].contentOpen) = true;**) onto that array button. I know this can be done in AS, but I need to know how to do this in jQuery.

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but I'm assuming you need to keep a state for each button (open/closed) so you know if you need to open or close the associated content box.

For this, you can use the data() function in jQuery:

```
jQuery.each(imageOptions, function (k) {
    $(imageOptions[k]).click(function() {
        if ($(this).data("open") == "true") {
             // hide content
             $(this).data("open","false");
        } else {
             // show content
             $(this).data("open","true");
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Awesome, lovin it! Thank you Dan!

Answer (score 2):

why won't you use [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to store values?

example

```
$('button').click(function(){

    if ($('div#window').data('contentOpen') ) {
        // means open
        $('div#window').data('contentOpen',false); // set it to close
        // do something here
    } else {
        // means close
        $('div#window').data('contentOpen',true); // set it to open
        // do something here
    }


})
```

Comment: Awesome thanks Reigel. I was not aware of the the data option!

Answer (score 0):

you could create an array of anonym objects to accomplish this e.g.

```
var imageOptions = ['.corporateNeeds', '.marketResearch', '.corpStrategic', '.employeeTraining', '.administration', '.wellnessManagement']; 
var options = [{ selector: ".option1", contentOpen: false }, { selector: ".option2", contentOpen: false }, { selector: ".option3", contentOpen: false }]; 



jQuery.each(imageOptions, function (k) { 
    $(imageOptions[k]).click(function () { 
        hideOptions() 
        $(options[k].selector).fadeIn(); 
        options[k].contentOpen = true; 
    }); 

});
```

Comment: So you can dot notate a variable onto the array then? Cool, but I learned something new with jQuery's data() today ;)

Thanks Marc

Comment: @sixfoot yes because your variable isnt just a string anymore but an object. of course jquery.data() is the better solution in your case.